# Specified cast is not valid for the date picker

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, nullable, informix

I try to check null before evaluate the date in my picker because i allow to enter no date :

```
 <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rpick_to_date" runat="server" Visible="false" SelectedDate='<%# Eval("to_date") == null ? "" : Eval("to_date") %>'>
                                            <Calendar UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False" ViewSelectorText="x">
                                            </Calendar>
                                            <DatePopupButton HoverImageUrl="" ImageUrl="" />
                                            <DateInput DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy">
                                            </DateInput>
 </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

---

but i get the following error all the time :

> Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: What is `to_date`? is it a nullable datetime or...?

Comment: it's `nullable` date `informix` database

Comment: Get rid of the inline Eval code and start playing with some hard-coded strings to see what can and what can't be cast as a 'SelectedDate'. It may be that this won't accept string.empty or it may be, as @simonlchilds has mentioned, that you're attempting to evaluate whether a non-nullable datetime is null or not and mightn't like it. It could just be that the value of "to_date" is not an acceptable date format?

Comment: if you just try to pass in `Eval("to_date")` and let the Rad Control handle it being null what happens?

Comment: Maybe you need to use [`DbSelectedDate`](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/calendar/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-with-raddatepicker.aspx) instead

Comment: thanks alot for all of u
@V4Vendetta:
Could u post it as an answer because this fixes my problom

Comment: @just_name Added as answer :) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should be using `DbSelectedDate` property to bind the value instead of `SelectedDate`

> Use the DbSelectedDate property than SelectedDate to get or set the
>   date content of RadDatePicker in a database friendly way. The only
>   difference with SelectedDate is that it will not throw an exception if
>   the new value is null or DBNull. Setting a null value will internally
>   revert the SelectedDate to the null value, i.e. the input value will
>   be empty.

[From here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/calendar/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-with-raddatepicker.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (Delete string "" ) - `SelectedDate` is `Nullable<DateTime>`

```
SelectedDate='<%# Eval("to_date")%>'
```